# input and output of cmd command

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, cmd, set

I have next script `test.bat`:

```
@ECHO OFF

echo output inVal = %inVal%
SET /p inVal="input "
echo output inVal = %inVal%

dir  >NUL 2>&1
if %errorlevel% == 1 (
    echo non existing dir
) else (
    echo existing dir
    SET /p inVal="input "
    echo output inVal = %inVal%
)
```

And the output after my inputs is:

```
> test.bat
output inVal = 5
input 7
output inVal = 7
existing dir
input 3
output inVal = 7
>
> test.bat
output inVal = 3
input 8
output inVal = 8
existing dir
input 2
output inVal = 8
>
```

**first question**: on the second run, the output starts with number 3, that should be the last output from the first run, but for some reason it is not. Why?

**second question**: in second run, the last output should be 2, instead, it is 8: "`output inVal = 8`" Why?

Comment: **DIR** is an internal command, _there isn't a dir executabe to not exist_, and there really is no need to check for it.

Comment: `IF` evaluates `%inVal%` in `echo output inVal = %inVal%` before `SET /p inVal="input "` assigns a new one. You can either enable delayed expansion and use `!inVal!` or you can use `goto` and labels to emulate this shortcoming of the `IF` and `ELSE` blocks.

Comment: what is expansion ?

Comment: can you tell me how can I use `goto and labels` in this example ?